# different repositories of different project in same query

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, dependency-injection, ninject

I am using ASP.NET MVC3 with Entity Framework using generic repository pattern with DI (Ninject).

I have a main project (class library) that other sites connect to it. the main project has it's own repositories and own context (it's own .edmx file) which connect to the common tables . Each site has it's own repositories which connect to it's own tables. My problem is that when I try to run complex linq queries that combine both the site tables with the main project tables, I get "different contexts in the same query" exception.  please, can you tell me What am I doing wrong?

exception Type:

> system notSupported exception

exception message:

> The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are
>   associated with different contexts.

this is the stackTrace:

> System.Data.Objects.ELinq.Funcletizer.FuncletizingVisitor.InlineObjectQuery(ObjectQuery
>   inlineQuery, Type expressionType)    at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.Funcletizer.FuncletizingVisitor.InlineValue(Expression
>   expression, Boolean recompileOnChange)    at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.Funcletizer.FuncletizingVisitor.Visit(Expression
>   exp)    at
>   System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.VisitExpressionList(ReadOnlyCollection'1
>   original)    at
>   System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression
>   m)    at
>   System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp) 
>   at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.Funcletizer.FuncletizingVisitor.Visit(Expression
>   exp)    at
>   System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.VisitLambda(LambdaExpression
>   lambda)    at
>   System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp) 
>   at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.Funcletizer.FuncletizingVisitor.Visit(Expression
>   exp)    at
>   System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.VisitUnary(UnaryExpression
>   u)    at
>   System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp) 
>   at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.Funcletizer.FuncletizingVisitor.Visit(Expression
>   exp)    at
>   System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.VisitExpressionList(ReadOnlyCollection'1
>   original)    at
>   System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression
>   m)    at
>   System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp) 
>   at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.Funcletizer.FuncletizingVisitor.Visit(Expression
>   exp)    at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.Funcletizer.Funcletize(Expression
>   expression, Func'1& recompileRequired)    at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter..ctor(Funcletizer
>   funcletizer, Expression expression)    at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.CreateExpressionConverter() 
>   at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable'1
>   forMergeOption)    at
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery'1.GetResults(Nullable'1
>   forMergeOption)    at
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery'1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalQuery'1.GetEnumerator()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery'1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
>   at System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView'1.get_Items()

Comment: Please explain what "a main project that other sites connect to it" and "The code shout he cannot use two different dbcontext" means. Is an exception thrown? If so, please post the message, exception type and stack trace.

Comment: You can only combine the data from the different contexts if you first convert them to IEnumerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about it: You have two different contexts that conceptually represent two different database connections, so hypothetically as far as EF is concerned could be even two different databases on two different servers. You simply cannot do a join over the data contained in two separate servers *in the database context* - that is why EF is enforcing that you use the same context so that its abstraction still works.

As @GertArnold suggested in the comments the only feasible way is to grab the relevant data from data source A, grab the relevant data from data source B and do the join in memory (that's what `.AsEnumerable()` essentially will do). Now in most cases you do not want to do this, since you will materialize much more data into memory than necessary.

So think strongly about refactoring your code to use a unit of work pattern so the repositories can use the *same context* to avoid this problem. This could be as easy as passing in the context to your class library classes using constructor injection.

Comment: asEnumerable() gonna be too heavy on my memory and ToList() gonna cause performence issue. The "unit of work" Sounds interesting. Can you please demonstrate? How can I make both my repositories which both have a different .edmx file (different projects using the database first approach) use the same context?

Comment: if you can elaborate a little more I very much appreciate it.